# Android Studio Video Player buttons and list index

Tags: android, button, video, android-video-player

I am learning Android Studio and java, my level is totaly beginner but I am trying to make video player with simple buttons: `Previous`, `Next`, `exit` and option checkbox for random video from list.

So far it's working but just once, next clicks are just starting same video from beginning. Can someone have mercy and help me? I was looking for some codes for 3 days.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<VideoView
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Następny"
    android:id="@+id/next"
    android:layout_below="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/videoView" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Poprzedni"
    android:id="@+id/prev"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/next"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Wyjście"
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Losowo"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/prev"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start/Stop"
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
package no.norskavis.norw1;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });
        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    final List listA = new ArrayList<>();

        listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc1);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc2);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc3);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc4);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc5);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc6);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc7);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc8);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc9);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc10);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc11);




                CheckBox chck= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

                if (chck.isEnabled()) {



                    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
                    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        Object randomItem = listA.get(new Random().nextInt(listA.size()));
                        @Override


                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Uri video = Uri.parse((String) randomItem);
                            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                                                    }
                                                                    }
                                            );
                                        }
                else

                { Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
                    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(View v){
                                                    ListIterator<String> listIterator = listA.listIterator();
                                                    Uri video = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(listIterator.nextIndex()));
                                                    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                                                                            }
                                                                    }
                                            );
                }
    }
```

Comment: Are you try to learn Android Studio ?

Comment: this is not android studio learning problem. it is your java logic problem.

Comment: I am new to java and android studio, so I am asking for some tips from someone that knows it. Is there someone who can explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found problems with buttons, random and next index in my app and this is how I fixed:

```
package no.norskavis.norw1;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }

    });
        final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.start();
    final List listA = new ArrayList<>();
        listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc1);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc2);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc3);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc4);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc5);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc6);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc7);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc8);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc9);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc10);
    listA.add("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.czesc11);




        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            CheckBox chck = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            ListIterator listIterator = listA.listIterator();

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Object randomItem = listA.get(new Random().nextInt(listA.size()));

                if (chck.isChecked()) {
                    Uri video = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(randomItem));
                    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                    videoView.start();
                } else {
                    Uri video = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(listIterator.next()));
                    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                    videoView.start();

                }


            }
        });
        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (videoView.isPlaying())
                {
                    videoView.pause();
                }
                else
                {
                    videoView.start();
                }

            }});

    }







}
```